# type 'Future<List<Data>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Data>' in type cast

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am getting the data from server and trying to set it in a grid view but I am getting error:

```
type 'Future<List<Data>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Data>' in type cast
```

Here is my Data Class:

```
class Data with ChangeNotifier {
Data({
  this.name,
  this.image,
});

final String image;
final String name;


factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
print(json['title'].toString());
return Data(
  name: json['title'].toString(),
  image: json['image'].toString(),
 );

}
}
```

And this is my Data_screen where I am calling this:

```
 var datas= Provider.of<Datas>(context).fetchData() as List<Data>;
 var datalength = datas.length;
```

Widget:

```
 Expanded(
            child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(

                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28, right: 28, bottom: 58),
              itemCount: datas.length,

              itemBuilder: (context, index) => DataCard(
                datas[index],
                index: index,
                onPress: () {
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

And in Datas.dart:

```
 Future<List<Data>> fetchData() async {
 var response = await http.get(url);
 var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
 print(responseJson);
 return (responseJson['datas'])
    .map<Data>((p) => Data.fromJson(p))
  .toList();
```

}

Comment: var datas= Provider.of<Datas>(context).fetchData() as Future<List<Data>>;  try this. because of fetchData function return type.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I tried this but then I get error in widget for datas[index] and datas.length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is so clear. You cannot cast from `List<Data>` to `Future<List<Data>>`. Try to use:

```
List<Data> fetchData() async {
 var response = await http.get(url);
 var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
 print(responseJson);
 return (responseJson['datas'])
    .map<Data>((p) => Data.fromJson(p))
  .toList();
}
```

OR return a new `Future` with the `List<Data>`

```
Future<List<Data>> fetchData() async {
 var response = await http.get(url);
 var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
 print(responseJson);
 var response = (responseJson['datas'])
    .map<Data>((p) => Data.fromJson(p))
  .toList();
 return Future.value(response)
}
```

It just an idea(without testing)

Comment: When I change to the code provided by you I get error in the return statement: The return type 'dynamic' isn't a 'List<Data>', as defined by the method 'fetchData'.dart(return_of_invalid_type) .

Comment: When I debug i found I that I am getting error on this line: var response = await http.get(url);

Comment: Have you tried with `Future.value()` ? I edited my answer(in the OR section)